# Facebook API Realtime Page's likes (aka "fan_count")

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve Facebook page's likes (aka `fan_count`) in real time using Webhooks?

My webhook is already functional and I do receive likes on post, new comments, … everything but likes on the page itself.

I subscribed to pretty much every topics possible (`feed`, `mentions`, …).